# git push from windows client to windows client

Tags: windows, git

Usually, git is used in scenario where some "main" server can be used to push code to and from. However currently my company server is offline.

How can I push repo from one windows client to another?

(I use Git Bash, but any software can be installed)

Comment: If you want to use your local git repository on a different machine, copy the whole directory tree.

Comment: Nice, but I was actually thinking about taking advantage of git's decentralized nature. After all central repo is just convince/backup. Just do not know how to do that on Windows.

Comment: Are you wanting to push to an existing repo on another client?